# Non-existence of classical solutions of Hardy PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity, heat-equation

On the paper "[On the Cauchy Problem for Reaction-Diffusion Equations](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-337-02/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5/S0002-9947-1993-1153016-5.pdf)" Wang studies the Hardy-Hénon equation
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t -  \Delta u =  |\cdot|^{l}u^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\  
{u}(0) =  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \\
\end{cases}.
$$
On page 554 he says that "when $l<0$ it is generally impossible to obtain a classical solution for the equation". I was curious if there really isn't any classical solution, or if there aren't mathematical methods yet to determine whether or not there is a classical solution. In the case $l<0$ it deals only with mild solutions. Has there been any progress in the literature in this direction?

Comment: Well, there's an obvious obstruction: if $u$ is a classical (i.e. $C^2$) solution, and $u > 0$ (this is preserved if the initial condition is positive by the maximum principle, for example), and $l < 0$, then you have a contradiction. The left hand side is bounded, but the right hand side blows up at $x = 0$ (I assume the $\cdot$ is $x$ here?). So if you are going to look for a solution, you shouldn't expect a $C^2$ one.

Comment: Got it, I imagined he can't use standard parabolic regularity results, so he came to this conclusion.